# UseHsts not working with NetCore 2.1 Website

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I followed the directions at [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#hsts) for configuring UseHsts, but when I hit my website, I do not see the Strict-Transport-Security header.  I tried several variations on the configuration, but nothing seems to have any affect.  Any ideas what I am missing?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddHsts(options =>
    {
    });

    services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
    {
    });            
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHsts();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

This is an image of the headers that I get in Chrome, but it looks the same in every other browser, as well.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

UseHsts excludes the following loopback hosts:

- localhost : The IPv4 loopback address.
- 127.0.0.1 : The IPv4 loopback address.
- [::1] : The IPv6 loopback address.

You could try to publish the web app and check the header **Strict-Transport-Security**.

Below is the result from publishing the site to Azure.

[image]

Comment: I finally got my app deployed to PCF Azure, and the header still doesn't show.  I don't suppose you have another idea.

Comment: Could you try to make a test with built-in Asp.Net Core MVC template? Also, try `services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);`

Comment: I tried manually setting CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1, but it did not change anything.

Comment: Also, I created a fresh 2.1 application using the VS template.  I see all of the code in there that sets up hsts, but it still does not produce the header.  This is after deploying the thing to PCF, so that it is not using localhost, and I changed ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to something other than Development, so that hsts would be enabled.

Comment: @Eric which browser did you use to access published web site? Could you share us a screen shot about the request and result?

Comment: Not sure how much it will help, but I updated the original question with a screen capture.

Comment: @Eric did you find the solutions to this? I configured this and I always received the response with Strict-Transport-Security : disabled

Comment: @WarrenG.  I ended up manually manipulating the header without using UseHsts.  I have been too busy with other things to go back and try again.

Answer (score 5):

This MAY be related, but I had the same issue then I was using middlewared in a wrong order. This configuration enabled the response header:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders();
app.UseHsts();
```

Of course, `services.AddHsts(...)` is also easy to miss.

Comment: This saved me hours of frustration. It appears that HSTS is not applied unless the connection is HTTPS (makes sense), and behind a TLS-terminating load balancer, `UseForwardedHeaders` is the only way to know that the connection is HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

Having the same issue, I came across [snippet](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Middleware/HttpsPolicy/test/HstsMiddlewareTests.cs#L208) from the HstsMiddleWare test code and found it useful

As mentioned in the previous answers, the UseHsts method excludes the loopback hosts but you can clear this list by making a call to the Clear method of the ExcludedHosts property

```
        services.AddHsts(options =>
        {
            options.ExcludedHosts.Clear();
            options.Preload = true;
            options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
            options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(60);
        });
```

NOTE: This is for the purposes of testing Hsts locally, but as mentioned in the official Microsoft documentation, it is not advisable to enable this in development "[because the HSTS settings are highly cacheable by browsers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#http-strict-transport-security-protocol-hsts)"

Comment: Thanks.  Saved me from pulling my hair out for even longer.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem in my ASP.NET Core 2.2 application. The [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#http-strict-transport-security-protocol-hsts) states there shouldn't be a need to set Max-Age explicitly in the AddHsts() method:

> Explicitly sets the max-age parameter of the Strict-Transport-Security header to 60 days. If not set, defaults to 30 days. See the max-age directive for more information.

However, by setting this myself I've managed to get the header added to the response.

In **ConfigureServices()** in Startup.cs:

```cs
if (!this.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    var currentDate = DateTime.Now;

    services.AddHsts(opt =>
    {
        opt.MaxAge = currentDate.AddYears(1) - currentDate;
        opt.IncludeSubDomains = true;
    });
}
```

In **Configure()** in Startup.cs:

```cs
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.ConfigureExceptionHandler(loggerFactory);
    app.UseHsts();
}
```

Example response headers from my hosted application:
[image]

**NOTE:** the other response headers I've added explicitly in my web.config.

Comment: You should be adding your code as text not as an image, see [Why not upload images of code on SO ...?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)